# Start kate editor in non-fullscreen mode

Tags: fullscreen, kate

**Problem**

Whenever I start kate, it opens in fullscreen mode. I can manually disable full screen mode via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, but I would like to start kate in non-fullscreen mode.

*Edit:* The problem also occurs when starting kate as root.

**What works**

Kile (which uses kate as editor) is not affected by the problem.

**Steps tried**

I deleted every kate configuration file using `rm ~/.config/kate*`, but this did not help.

**Sytem information**

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, Kate 15.12.3, KDE Frameworks 5.18.0, Qt 5.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out that in my case it was sufficient to delete

```
~/.local/share/kate/anonymous.katesession
```